# Pre-select option in dropdown menu with URL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I'm working with this code snippet:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// <![CDATA[
 $(document).ready(function() {
  // Parse your query parameters here, and assign them to a variable named `queryParams`
  var option = queryParams.type;
  $("#GCValue").val(option);
 });
 // ]]>
</script>
```

I don't have a lot of latitude with how I can affect the page, this is in the `<body>` section of the page, since I don't have access to the `<head>` tag.

I have this form:

```
<select id=GCValue>
  <option val="10">10</option>
  <option val="25">25</option>
  <option val="50">50</option>
  <option val="100">100</option>
  <option val="250">250</option>
</select>
```

and I would like to use the URL of the page to select one of these five options (currently default is 10). I think it's supposed to be either `https://www.mywebsite.com/gift-card/?type=2` or `https://www.mywebsite.com/gift-card/?GCValue=2` but neither work. I'm pretty new to JS and JQuery, so I know I have to be doing something wrong. Any help appreciated.

Comment: at first glance. The ?GCValue=2 does not exist in your option.

Comment: also. there's a missing attribute for select method. 
maybe`.change();` attribute. or `$('#GCValue option[value=10]').attr('selected','selected')`;

Comment: @JuliusLimson Doing `$("#GCValue").val(option)` is far simpler than querying for the `<option>` and using `attr()`

Answer (score 0):

According to your code your URL should be something like

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/gift-card/?type=10
```

You have to pass the option values to the URL instead of the option indexes based on your current code.